# connection between trace and determinant to matrices similarity in 2X2 matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

i'm struggling explaing these statments

Let A,B be matrices of order 2X2 over R

1. given det(A)=det(B)=4 and tr(A)=tr(B)=7    A is similar to B ( should be True)
2. given det(A)=det(B)=4 and tr(A)=tr(B)=4    A is similar to B ( should be false)

i found that the charcristic polynomiala of the two statments are
(1) t^2 -7t + 4
(2) t^2 -4t + 4 = (t-2)^2

over R, (1) is not Diagonalizable, and (2) is , what am i missing ? how can i determine these statments ?

what is the connection between trace and determinant here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the eigenvalues of these matrices, then $\alpha\ne\beta$. So, $A$ and $B$ are similar to $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}\alpha&0\\0&\beta\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.
2. Consider $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}2&0\\0&2\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ and $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}2&1\\0&2\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, which are *not* similar. However both have determinant equal to $4$ and trace also equal to $4$.

Comment: and when the trace is 7 ?
what's the diffrence ?

Comment: The trace being $7$ alone means nothing. But the trace being $7$ together with the determinant being $4$ means that the eigenvalues of the matrix are the roots of the polynomial $x^2-7x+4$. But, since $(-7)^2-4\times4\ne0$, this polynomial has distinct roots. Therefore, the matrix is a $2\times2$ matrix with two distinct eigenvalues. So, it is diagonalizable.